# How to manage a multi-step form with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Here is the code of my multistep form:

```
import clsx from 'clsx';
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { makeStyles, withStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
import Step from '@material-ui/core/Step';
import Stepper from '@material-ui/core/Stepper';
import StepLabel from '@material-ui/core/StepLabel';
import StepConnector from '@material-ui/core/StepConnector';
import { Container, Row, Col, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

import Description from '@material-ui/icons/Description';
import AccountCircle from '@material-ui/icons/AccountCircle';
import DirectionsCar from '@material-ui/icons/DirectionsCar';

import Step1 from '../components/Step1';
import Step2 from '../components/Step2';
import Step3 from '../components/Step3';

const styles = () => ({
  root: {
    width: '90%',
  },
  button: {
    marginRight: '0 auto',
  },
  instructions: {
    marginTop: '0 auto',
    marginBottom: '0 auto',
  },
});

const ColorlibConnector = withStyles({ 
  alternativeLabel: {
    top: 22,
  },
  active: {
    '& $line': {
      backgroundColor: '#00b0ff',
    },
  },
  completed: {
    '& $line': {
      backgroundColor: '#00b0ff',
    },
  },
  line: {
    height: 3,
    border: 0,
    backgroundColor: '#eaeaf0',
    borderRadius: 1,
  },
})(StepConnector);

const useColorlibStepIconStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: '#ccc',
    zIndex: 1,
    color: '#fff',
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    display: 'flex',
    borderRadius: '50%',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  active: {
    backgroundColor: '#00b0ff',
    boxShadow: '0 4px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.25)',
  },
  completed: {
    backgroundColor: '#00b0ff',
  },
});

function ColorlibStepIcon(props) {
  const classes = useColorlibStepIconStyles();
  const { active, completed } = props;

  const icons = {
    1: <AccountCircle />,
    2: <DirectionsCar />,
    3: <Description />,
  };

  return (
    <div
      className={clsx(classes.root, {
        [classes.active]: active,
        [classes.completed]: completed,
      })}
    >
      {icons[String(props.icon)]}
    </div>
  );
}

function getSteps() {
  return ['Dati Assicurato', 'Dati Veicolo', 'Dati Assicurazione'];
}

function getStepContent(step) {
  switch (step) {
    case 0:
      return <Step1/>;
    case 1:
      return <Step2/>;
    case 2:
      return <Step3/>;;
    default:
      return 'Unknown step';
  }
}

class HorizontalLinearStepper extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activeStep: 0,
      agencyData: {}
    };
  }

  static propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.object,
  };

  isStepOptional = step => {
    return step === 1;
  };

  handleNext = () => {
    const { activeStep } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      activeStep: activeStep + 1,
    });
  };

  handleBack = () => {
    const { activeStep } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      activeStep: activeStep - 1,
    });
  };

  handleReset = () => {
    this.setState({
      activeStep: 0,
    });
  };

  logout = () => {
    localStorage.clear();
    this.props.history.push('/');
  }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const steps = getSteps();
    const { activeStep } = this.state;

    return (
      <Container fluid>
        <div className={classes.root}>
          <Stepper alternativeLabel activeStep={activeStep} connector={<ColorlibConnector />}>
            {steps.map((label, index) => {
              const props = {};

              return (
                <Step key={label} {...props}>
                  <StepLabel StepIconComponent={ColorlibStepIcon}>{label}</StepLabel>
                </Step>
              );
            })}
          </Stepper>

          <div>
            {activeStep === steps.length ? (
              <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
                <h1 style={{textAlign: 'center', paddingTop: 100, color: '#7fc297'}}>
                  TERMINATO
                </h1>
                <h4 style={{textAlign: 'center', paddingTop: 50}}>
                  Tutti gli step sono stati completati con successo! 
                </h4>  
                <h4 style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>  
                  Procedi con la generazione del QR Code.
                </h4>
                <Row style={{marginTop: '40px'}} className='justify-content-center align-items-center text-center'>
                  <Col md={{span: 3}}>
                    <Button 
                      style={{borderRadius: 30, borderWidth: 0, height: 50, width: 150, backgroundColor: '#f32a19', borderColor: '#f32a19'}}
                      disabled={activeStep === 0} 
                      onClick={this.handleReset} 
                    >
                      Annulla
                    </Button>
                  </Col>
                  <Col md={{span: 3}}>
                    <Button
                        style={{borderRadius: 30, borderWidth: 0, height: 50, width: 150, backgroundColor: '#00b0ff'}}
                        onClick={() => console.log('Click')}
                      >
                      Procedi
                    </Button>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </div>
            ) : 
            (
              <Container style={{}}>
                <h2 className={classes.instructions}>{getStepContent(activeStep)}</h2>
                <Row className='justify-content-center align-items-center text-center'>
                  <Col md={{span: 3}}>
                    <Button 
                      style={{marginTop: 10, backgroundColor: 'gold', borderRadius: 30, borderWidth: 0, height: 50, width: 150}}
                      disabled={activeStep === 0} 
                      onClick={this.handleBack} 
                    >
                      Indietro
                    </Button>
                  </Col>
                  <Col md={{span: 3}}>
                    {
                      activeStep === steps.length - 1 ?
                      <Button
                        style={{marginTop: 10, borderRadius: 30, borderWidth: 0, height: 50, width: 150, backgroundColor: '#7fc297'}}
                        onClick={this.handleNext}
                      >
                      Finito
                      </Button>
                      :
                      <Button
                        style={{marginTop: 10, backgroundColor: '#00b0ff', borderRadius: 30, borderWidth: 0, height: 50, width: 150}}
                        onClick={this.handleNext}
                      >
                      Avanti
                      </Button>
                    }
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </Container>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(HorizontalLinearStepper);
```

It is composed of three steps and at each step I ask for many data.

This is the code of one of the `Step` (they are all the same, the difference are the contents of the input fields):

```
import React from 'react';
import { Container, Row, Col, Form } from 'react-bootstrap';

export default function Step2(props) {

  return(
    <Container>
      <Row style={{marginTop: '30px'}} className='h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center'>
        <Col md={{ span: 6 }} className='text-center my-auto'>
          <h3 style={{marginBottom: '1rem'}}>Dati Veicolo</h3>
          <Form>
            <Form.Row>
              <Form.Group as={Col}>
                <Form.Control
                  type='text' 
                  placeholder='Marca' 
                  required
                />
              </Form.Group>
              <Form.Group as={Col}>
                <Form.Control
                  type='text' 
                  placeholder='Targa' 
                  required
                />
              </Form.Group>
            </Form.Row>
            <Form.Group>
              <Form.Control
                type='text' 
                placeholder='Paese immatricolazione' 
                required
              />
            </Form.Group>
            <h6 style={{marginBottom: '1rem'}}>Possiede un rimorchio?</h6>              
            <Form.Group>
              <Form.Control
                type='text' 
                placeholder='Targa'
              />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group>
              <Form.Control
                type='text' 
                placeholder='Paese immatricolazione'
              />
            </Form.Group>
          </Form>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

What I need to do is to check for errors at each step before the users pass to the following one, so that they can start fulfilling the second step of the form only in the case they have completed the first step correctly, and so on ...
How can I do this check step by step?

Moreover how can I collect all the data that I ask for in the main component of the form so that I can work with all those data after the users have finished fulfilling the whole form?

At this [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-silence-w2n2z?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) there is the example

Comment: Please go easy on the ALL CAPS YELLING, especially in the title.

Comment: Also, please create a **minimal** reproduction example.

Comment: @tadman Sorry, I have the caps locked and I didn't notice

Comment: At least the whole question wasn't like that.

Comment: @JaredSmith I just edit the question adding a `codesandbox`

Comment: It is often recommended that you use a third-party library for handling forms (Formik, React-Forms, Redux-Forms). These make writing forms easier. If you're interested, i could provide you an example using either of the the two libraries on your codesandbox.

Comment: @AabhushanGautam Yes, I would be grateful. The important thing is that the front end part is like the one contained in my codesandbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You Component hierarchy seems good, I would like to add one thing to keep things together, like for steps you can create an Array inside a main component state like this

```
class Main extends React.Component{
    state = {
      ...OTHER_STATE_PROPERTIES,
      activeStep: 0 | 1| 2,
      steps: [{
        name: 'step-name',
        icon: 'icon-name',
        content: Form1 | Form2 | Form3, // this is optional, you can use getContent too
        data: {}
      }]
    }


    // pass this function as prop to every Form Component
    // We will talk about this function soon
    handleStepSubmit = (stepIndex, data) => {
      this.setState((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        activeIndex: prevState.activeIndex + 1,
        steps: prevState.map((step, index) => {
          if(stepIndex !== index){
            return step; 
          }
          return {
            ...step,
            data
          }
        })
      }))
    }
    //... Other stuff

}
```

Now each **Form** should have its own `state` (so that only the form gets re-render on input changes) and `form`, where you can handle input and validate them and send it to parent component step using props, so we need to add a function in the parent component. **`handleStepSubmit`** function will only be called after validation of data on `onSubmit` call of `form`

How to validate data is up to you, you can use

#### default input attributes like,

1. required
2. min, max for number
3. type (email)
4. pattern

#### Validate State using JS logic

#### Use [yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup)

#### Use [Formik](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/overview) with yup

This is what I prefer by using formik you don't have to worry about `onChange`, **validation** and many more things, you can provide it `validate` prop where you can write validation logic yourself or `validationSchema` prop where just yup schema should be given, it will not allow if `onSubmit` to trigger if validation fails, you can also *input attributes* with it, if form is simple. We have to call `handleStepSubmit` on `onSubmit`

P.S.: It maintains a local state

#### What we have

At step 0 we will have

```
// I am omitting other stuff for understanding
state:{
   activeStep: 0,
   steps: [
     {data: {}},
     {data: {}},
     {data: {}},
   ]
}
```

When user submits Form 1 we will have

```
// I am omitting other stuff for understanding
state:{
   activeStep: 1,
   steps: [
     {data: formOneData},
     {data: {}},
     {data: {}},
   ]
}
```

and so one now when `activeStep` is 3 you will have all the validated data in the state, Horray!! High-Five! You can also data from previous steps in further step if required as we have it all in our parent component state.

#### Example:

[image: Edit formik-example]

Comment: Thanks a lot for you detailed answer. Can you give me a little example of create and validate a form using `Formik`?

Comment: Hi, I have added an example similar to your use case with 2 forms using `formik` with and without `yup`, hope it helps

Comment: The last question, how can I integrate my step bar with your method?

Comment: Use stepper in parent component pass activeIndex from state to it

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand... Can you update you `CodeSandbox`? Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

I would use a routing that points to the same component so you could store the old form in either your state/reducer/localStorage (in fact anything you want) and once the current step is ok I would simply navigate the user to the next one.

I have made a demo [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-franklin-l4rx1?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) with this logic.

I hope it helps

Comment: I see your solution, but when I click on the submit button this error will be generated:
`Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
    in Form (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Route (at src/index.js:12)
    in Switch (at src/index.js:11)
    in div (at src/index.js:9)
    in App (at src/index.js:21)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at src/index.js:20)`

Comment: I have updated the codesandbox the error was happening because `currentForm` was undefined after the step 2. The code was really not optimised for this it was just to give you a general idea on how to do it.

Comment: I am currently working on something really similar for [strapi](https://strapi.io/) you can see the full implementation [here](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/pull/4577) (check out the file `strapi/packages/strapi-plugin-content-type-builder/admin/src/containers/FormModal/index.js`)  you will have a better idea.

Comment: Ok, but how can I intregrate my step bar?

Comment: I see only now that the link of the file `index.js` response whit `Not Found`

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if I understand your question you would like

- Create a multi-step form and do some validation of data on every step if fails then let the user refill the necessary data else move to next form data.
- At every stage store in the `state` or `store` and once the user completes all step then you would like to work locally with that data.

Since you chose to work locally with those data I prefer `redux-store` to `state` because for obvious reasons like using the form data in business logic and other parts of the react

I hope [image: Edit inspiring-babbage-81ejq] this might be useful...

However, this is a basic structure and even I know there are lots of caveats and many things could be abstracted...

Answer (score -2):

Save all form data to your states (even completed steps like current step).
For validating your given data you should arrange a handleChange function for each field.